# Unable to migrate my shopify app to shopify cli 3.0

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm trying to migrate my test app for shopify using this guide:
https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/migrate

My operating system is MacOs Catalina 10.15.17
node version: 16.15.1
ruby version: 2.6.3p62
shopify version: 2.19.0

I moved all the code in /web as suggested, I created web/shopify.web.toml file , shopify.app.toml file and package.json file as suggested, then I run

```
sudo npm install
```

During the process I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/davide/shopify-v1/node_modules/@shopify/ngrok
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./postinstall.js
npm ERR! ngrok - downloading binary https://bin.equinox.io/c/bNyj1mQVY4c/ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip
npm ERR! ngrok - downloading progress: ngrok - error storing binary to local file [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! ngrok - install failed, retrying
ngrok - downloading progress: 2372/7642723 (0.03%)ngrok - downloading binary https://bin.equinox.io/c/bNyj1mQVY4c/ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip
npm ERR! ngrok - downloading progress: ngrok - error storing binary to local file [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! ngrok - install failed, retrying
ngrok - downloading progress: 2372/7642723 (0.03%)ngrok - downloading binary https://bin.equinox.io/c/bNyj1mQVY4c/ngrok-v3-stable-darwin-amd64.zip
npm ERR! ngrok - downloading progress: ngrok - error storing binary to local file [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! ngrok - install failed [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/davide/.ngrok/aHR0cHM6Ly9iaW4uZXF1aW5veC5pby9jL2JOeWoxbVFWWTRjL25ncm9rLXYzLXN0YWJsZS1kYXJ3aW4tYW1kNjQuemlw.zip'
npm ERR! }
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed permissions to /Users/davide/.ngrok directory and retried, then I succeeded